# creating record with the ember-data basic-Adapter

Tags: ember-data

I have a few questions concerning using the basicAdapter api to createRecord. Assuming I have two models as shown below, and I want to create the parent record, wait for a response and then create a child record, is this the way to go about it:

```
App.Contact = DS.Model.extend({
  address: DS.belongsTo("App.OneChild") 
});

App.Address = DS.Model.extend({
  street: DS.attr("string")
});
```

Then I create the record in the routes model hook or in the model.

```
contact = App.Contact.sync = {
   createRecord: function(contact, process) {
    process(contact).save();
  });
},

contact.on('didCreate', async(function() {
 address = App.Address.sync = { 
    createRecord: function(address, process){
     process(address).save();
    });
 }
});
```

**question 2**

Can I also do a nested post like this. This is not a real code, I just adapted **the code for making an ajax getJson  find request** from their blog post **[here](http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/03/22/stabilizing-ember-data.html).**

```
  App.Contact.sync = {
   createRecord: function(contact, process) {
    $.post("/contacts/1/addresses/create", { contact_name: id   }).then(function(contact) {        
     process(contact)                 
      .primaryKey('contact_name')
      .camelizeKeys()
      .save();
     });
  }
```

**question 3**

Also, will I always need to define a **sync object** as above before  calling createRecord, if so, does it mean I can only call createRecord from the model where the sync function is defined. Or I can still call createRecord from the router or controller independent of where the **sync object** was defined. An example of this in code will be useful.

Thanks for looking at this.